# Analizar cada una de las IPs con pydnsbl python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un problema, necesito analizar 1000 ips publicas, verificar si estan reportadas, para esto encontre una libreria llamada pydnsbl, una a una funcina bien pero como puedo hacerlo masivamente con un archivo txt o csv donde tenga las 1000 ips y con pydnsbl pueda analizar una a una?

agradezco su ayuda.

```
import pydnsbl
ip = str(input("ingrese una ip: "))
ip_checker = pydnsbl.DNSBLIpChecker()    
blacklist = ip_checker.check(f'{ip}')
print(blacklist)
```

Comment: Escribe un ciclo `for ip in archivo:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta podría ser una aproximación rápida con txt

`ips.txt` file

```
1.1.1.1
9.9.9.9
8.8.8.8
```

`script:`

```
import pydnsbl


ip_checker = pydnsbl.DNSBLIpChecker()

with open('ips.txt') as file:
    ips = file.read().splitlines()

    for ip in ips:
        if ip_checker.check(ip).blacklisted:
            print(f"{ip} blacklisted")
```

Comment: Amigo eres un crack, funciona perfectamente, solo agregue dos lineas mas para ver el resultado de <DNSBLResult: 1.1.1.1 [BLACKLISTED] (2/56)> pero funciona. muchas gracias. saludos desde Colombia.

Comment: no hay de que! Saludos des de Catalunya!